# Executing a spec before and after the main spec by cypress

Tags: cypress

I need to execute `header.spec.js` after and before I ran the main tests. To ensure all passed

I am looking for something like this:

```
before(function () {
  // I want here to call header.spec.js
});

it(`check the work flow`, () => {
  // this is the main spec that will page context 
})

after(function () {
  // I want here to call footer.spec.js
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your `header.spec.js` and `footer.spec.js` are scripts which you want to just execute? They don't contain any tests? You're using `before` and `after` [Hooks](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#Hooks) correctly. To execute a Javascript file within these hooks, you can use `cy.exec()` command which is described [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/exec.html#Syntax). E.g. with Node.js, you'd run those files like this (assuming their in the same directory):

```js
cy.exec("node header.spec.js");
```

Hope I understood your situation correctly.